# Is there a way to make a command reset itself so it doesn't respond twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a guess the number command, and when the number is guessed you can keep spamming the number and it'll respond.

I want it so that the command resets itself and you have to run it again. Is there a way to do this? Here is my code for the command:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "guess",
    description: "guess a number after activating a command",
    async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
        const randomNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor("#FF0000").setTitle("Guess the number between 1 and 10!");
        message.channel.send(embed);

        await client.on("message", (message) => {
            if (message.content === `${randomNumber}`) {
                message.channel.send("You guessed correctly!");
            }
        });
    },
};
```

By the way, I am using a dynamic handler so you won't see what activates the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an event listener inside the event lister. The exported object is already inside a `client.on('message', fn)`.

This is a perfect use case for [message collectors](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) though. Collectors are useful when you want your bot to receive additional input after the first command was sent.

You can set up a filter to only collect messages from the user who typed the command. You can also set a time limit using the `time` option, or the maximum number of guesses accepted using the [`max` option](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions).

Inside the `.on('collect)` event, you can check if the response is valid or not and send a message based on that. When the correct number is guessed, we use the `collector.end()` method to stop collecting more messages.

Check a working example below; I've added some comments too:

```js
async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
  const numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
  const randomNumber = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  const maxWait = 30000; // in ms, so it's 30 sec
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setTitle('Guess the number between 1 and 10! ');

  await message.channel.send(embed);

  // filter checks if the response is from the author who typed the command
  // and if the response is one of the possible guesses
  const filter = (response) =>
    response.author.id === message.author.id &&
    numbers.includes(response.content.trim());

  const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
    // set up the max wait time the collector runs
    time: maxWait,
  });

  // fires when a response is collected
  collector.on('collect', (response) => {
    if (response.content.trim() === randomNumber) {
      message.channel.send(
        ` Woohoo, ${response.author}! \n\nYour guess is correct, my number was \`${randomNumber}\`.`,
      );
      // the guess is correct, so stop this collector and emit the "end" event
      collector.stop();
    } else {
      // another chance if the response is incorrect
      message.channel.send(
        `Oh, ${response.author}, \`${response.content}\` is not correct... \nDo you want to try another number?`,
      );
    }
  });

  // fires when the collector is finished collecting
  collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
    // only send a message when the "end" event fires because of timeout
    if (reason !== 'time') return;

    // if there are incorrect guesses
    if (collected.size > 0) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `Ah, ${message.author}. Out of ${collected.size} guess${
          collected.size > 1 ? 'es' : ''
        } you couldn't find the number \`${randomNumber}\`. I'm not saying you're slow, but no more guesses are accepted.`,
      );
    }

    message.channel.send(
      `Okay, ${message.author}, I'm bored and I can't wait any longer. No more guesses are accepted. At least you could have tried...`,
    );
  });
};
```

[image]